# Remix - marked as abstract error

Tags: solidity

sorry for the question, but I'm quite new with web3. I have the following simple contract. When compiling it got the error as contract have to marked as abstract. So, how to fixed the error, and what is it means?. Thank you.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract array {
    uint[] public arr;
    function inc(uint item) public {
        arr.push(item);
    }

    function len() public view returns (uint);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solidity, abstract contract is designed for at least one function without any implementation, which normally used for interface.

In your code, you have a small mistake at function len(), it should return something. Here is the corrected one.

```
function len() public view returns (uint) {
   return arr.length;
}
```

Comment: Work like champ, thank you!